# Stereo Panorama Player for cardboard

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I'm trying to create a **stereo 360 player** by using cardboard sdk for unity. I want to see 2 different panorama image created by 3ds max with 2 cameras in left and right view. But I found google sdk can only see a image in a sphere. If I created 2 sphere with different image texture and put left camera to a sphere and right camera to another sphere, it doesn't work.

What should I do? Could anyone give me some advice?

Thank you!

Best wishes,

Dobbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. set two sphere to two different layers, say, "LeftEyeLayer" and "RightEyeLayer".
2. in the inspector of Left Camera, set "Toggle Culling Mask" of component "Cardboard Eye" to be "RightEyeLayer":
   [image: set Toggle Culling Mask to be "RightEyeLayer" in component of "Cardboard Eye" for the inspector of Left Camera]
3. do the same for the Right Camera, this time set "Toggle Culling Mask" to be "LeftEyeLayer".

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is very helpful for me. But I also have a question, why do we set "RightEyeLayer" to the Left Camera and "LeftEyeLayer" to the Right Camera?

Comment: That Culling Mask will be excluded. If you look into the code of CardboardEye, in the method "CopyCameraAndMakeSideBySide", it will be excluded from the eye's(i.e. the left or right camera's) vision: cam.cullingMask ^= toggleCullingMask.value; In this case, when we assign RightEyeLayer to Left Camera, the Left Camera won't see objects in RightEyeLayer.

Comment: Yeah! It's right. But in my project, there are severe twisting effect in the panorama image(mainly in top and down region). How can I reduce it? Could I contact you with email or qq? My qq is 459642390. Thank you!

Comment: Make your sphere big enough, say, scale x y z to 10000, and meanwhile make sure the far clipping plane of the main camera to be outside of the sphere so the sphere won't be clipped. You can contact me at zengxiaoqi@gmail.com.